# Can't run Adobe Dreamweaver with wine on Kali

Tags: linux, wine, dreamweaver

I'm trying to run Dreamweaver.exe with Wine on my Kali Machine but I get the following error with this command:

> wine Dreamweaver.exe

```
wine: Bad EXE format for Z:\root\Desktop\Dreamweaver.exe
```

What can I do about it ?

I installed Dreamwaver on my windows Machine and just drag the .exe on my virtual Kali Machine. But I see there are a lot of .ddl files in the same directory, maybe should I use them with Wine ?

Any suggestion ?

Cheers

Comment: @Tealkine I see, but what if the insta.exe is a 64 bits ?

Answer (score 0):

Try installing DreamWeaver directly using Wine.

If you just copy and paste the .exe, many related files wont be copied. If you install software on Windows, the installer will extract files to directories like C:/Users/YourUser/AppData, ../YourUser/Documents and so on. Some of those files are also hidden sometimes, so if you just copy and paste it to your Linux system you will miss some files.